# Reverse ?? operator

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do something like this in C#?

`logger != null ? logger.Log(message) : ; // do nothing if null`

or

`logger !?? logger.Log(message); // do only if not null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

:)

```
if (logger!=null) logger.Log(message);
```

---

No... unfortunately such an operator does not exist.

### UPD [31.07.2020]:

Since C# 6, you can do it with null-conditional operator like this:

```
logger?.Log(message);
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

> Available in C# 6 and later, a null-conditional operator applies a member access, ?., or element access, ?[], operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns null.

Comment: Yeah. For HeavyWave it's unfortunately since that is what he was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to be too clever... Just use an `if`:

```
if(logged != null) logger.Log(message);
```

Answer (score 8):

No.  The closest you can come is probably via a null object design:

```
(logger ?? NullLogger.Instance).Log(message);
```

where NullLogger.Instance is a Logger that just no-ops all its methods.  (Of course, if you require the default behaviour to do something rather than no-op-ing, you can substitute a suitable Logger.Default or whatever instead of the NullLogger.Instance.)

Answer (score 4):

Or, if you like surprising your co-workers, you could use an extension method:

```
public static void Log(this Logger logger, string message)
{
    if(logger != null)
        logger.ReallyLog(message);
}
```

and just do

```
logger = null;
logger.Log("Hello world, not.");
```

Comment: I think your co-workers should (rightfully) nail you in a code review for doing something like this though. :)

Comment: It's nice, but doesn't work (at least when I try it).  The Logger.Log method takes precedence over the extension method, so you end up with a NullReferenceException.  Of course you can work around this by renaming the extension method SafeLog or something like that.

Comment: @itowlson - You could always just move the non-static Log() method out of the original class and implement it using only the extension method!

Comment: @itowlson - got me. But the name of the extension method has to be "Log" to allow for maximum surprise.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a reverse ?? operator too, so I bumped onto this old question that can be answered today thanks to the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), which was introduced in C# 6:

```
logger?.Log(message);
```

This will call the `Log` method only if `logger` is not null :)